# Bash regex to compare elements of substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

We have a command that returns output in the form of the following table:

```
ogd       started           1/1         256M
lap       started           ?/1         1G 
ice       started           1/2         2G
ev1       started           2/2         1G 
pip       stopped           0/1         128M 
qip       stopped           ?/2         128M 
pld       stopped           0/1         128M
```

Ideally we need the third column to be `1/1` or `2/2`, therefore we need a oneliner (maybe `awk` or `sed`) to filter out the lines where the two numbers in the third column do not match. The output corresponding to the input above would be the following:

```
lap       started           ?/1         1G 
ice       started           1/2         2G
pip       stopped           0/1         128M 
qip       stopped           ?/2         128M 
pld       stopped           0/2         128M
```

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: "We need one line command" is not a question.

Comment: Try this: `your output | awk '{split($3,a,"/"); if (a[1] != a[2]) print $0 }'`

Comment: Thanks nbari. This is what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by nbari in the comments, this is a possible solution:

`our command | awk '{split($3,a,"/"); if (a[1] != a[2]) print $0 }'`